# python virtualenv os.py not found although exists in system wide

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

With `virtualenv` version 1.10.1 I've created `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/django-app-env/` however running it with the following `passenger_wsgi.py`

```
import sys, os
app_name = 'app'
env_name = 'django-app-venv'

cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(cwd + '/' + app_name)

INTERP = cwd + '/' + env_name + '/bin/python'
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/' + env_name + '/bin')
sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/' + env_name + '/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')
sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/' + env_name + '/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", app_name + ".settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I get...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 325, in <module> app_module = load_app()
File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 62, in load_app
return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
File "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/passenger_wsgi.py", line 10, in <module>
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
File "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/django-app-env/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 312, in execl
execv(file, args)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Its Python 2.7.5

Why?

Comment: Can you import it from a shell with the virtual environment activated?

Comment: It's not saying that the `os` module doesn't exist, it's saying that [`os.execv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execv) is trying to execute a file that doesn't exist. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman I have completely rewritten the question.  Can you still help?

Comment: I would try hard coding that directory instead of using getcwd().

Comment: I did solve it.   I had to put the virtual environment and the app directory in the same folder.  Previous I had the app folder inside the httpdocs folder with the environment folder a level up.   I also switched some nginx switches to stop Apache being involved.  Thanks for the suggestions though.